# Two flat tori are isometric iff their lattices are isometric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Say $T_1,T_2$ are flat tori defined as quotients of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the lattices $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2$, resp. It is easy to prove that an isometry $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ sending $\Gamma_1\to\Gamma_2$ must descend to an isometry $T_1\to T_2$. How can one prove the converse: that if there exists an isometry $T_1\to T_2$, one can lift it to an isometry $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ (which sends $\Gamma_1\mapsto\Gamma_2$)?

Comment: Intuitively, it seems pretty straightforward to me: your map $T_1 \to T_2$ gives you a family of maps between any two fundamental domains for $T_1$ and $T_2$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$; then it's just a matter of choosing one and stitching the rest together following the relevant boundary conditions. I don't think that the fact that the map is an isometry plays any role here, but I may be wrong.

Comment: An isometry of metric spaces induces an isometry of their universal covers once you choose where to send a single point in the universal cover.

Comment: A.P., yeah I reckon you're right, thet fact that $T_1\to T_2$ is an isometry is only used to prove that $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is an isometry.

Comment: Oh, you're right Mike, I'm being silly :)